# Capacitor 3 iOS support

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a simple question, but did not found clear answer. In the documenation of capacitor 3 is this information:

*Capacitor 3 supports iOS 12+. Xcode 12+ is required. CocoaPods 1.8+ is recommended.*
(https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0)

Does it mean that older versions of iOS (11, 10, 9) are not supported yet and the application built with Capacitor3 will just NOT work on it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it means that, iOS 11 and older are not supported anymore.

Capacitor 2 supports iOS 11 and newer, iOS 10 and older where never supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is a little bit pity that older versions are not supported.

Comment: Well, it's a little percentage of devices https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/